# Does every language belong to either P or NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, np

Why I am reading the book about Theory of Computation of Michael Sipser, I have a small question: Does every language belong to either P or NP?

Comment: There are languages "under", like the ones in class NL, and other "over", like the ones in class EXPSPACE. I think if you continue reading that book will talk about them.

Comment: Thank you. I've reached the spot you talked about :)

Comment: @FabioF. Isn't NL a subset of P?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, not all languages in in P or NP. Here are a few ways to see this:

1. There are uncountably many languages, but only countably many languages in P and NP. That means, in particular, that if you choose a language at random, with probability 1 you choose a language not in P or NP.
2. All languages in P and NP are decidable. Any undecidable language, such as the halting problem, cannot be in NP.
3. The [nondeterministic time hierarchy theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem) can be used to show that there are languages in NEXP that are not in NP.

Hope this helps!